# How to 'bind' query to a grid, in Axapta?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

How can i bind a 'complex' query with, for example, 3 joined table to a grid in Axapta ? For 'bind' i intend: show in a grid a list of field in the resulted query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If complex then make a query, then drag the query and drop on the `Data Sources` node.

The joined tables (maybe exclusive exists joined tables) are automatically created for you.
You may then change the nodes.

Any grid should address the first datasource. You drag the grid fields from the created datasources `Fields` list.

You can do the same without the query using multiple datasources provided proper relations are defined and you use `LinkType` `InnerJoin` and `JoinSource` the first datasource.

See [Creating a Form Based on a Composite Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc566883%28v=ax.50%29.aspx).

Comment: Drag and drop the query on the DataSource ? How can i do this in Ax 2009 ? Is it really possible ? Thanks Jan.

Comment: Ahaha, you're right! Yes, now i know that i can create a query into AOT under Query section, and ..drag into my datasource. Thanks a lot!